# Why is my math with Doubles coming out wrong?

Tags: java, math, double

This is how I am creating q

```
Double q = ((r * (i/5)) + y);
```

at this point the values of the other variables are

```
r = 3.470694142992069E-5
i = 1
y = -116.30237535361584
```

but

```
q = -116.30237535361584
```

is there something wrong with this math? ( Java )

```
q should be -116.30236841222755
```

Comment: Better use the primitive type `double` instead of the class `Double` for simple double values.

Comment: thank you today I forgot about the primitive type and used to all through my code, lot of refraction to be done

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i and 5 are both integers, so the (i/5) portion evaluates to an integer (0). That negates the multiplication by r, so you're left with only the value for y.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
Double q = ((r * ((double)i/5)) + y);
```

Here's the complete code.

```
class Main
{
        public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
        {
                double r = 3.470694142992069E-5;
                int i = 1;
                double y = -116.30237535361584;
                Double q = ((r * ((double)i/5)) + y);
                System.out.println(q);

        }
}
```

> Output:
>   -116.30236841222755

Comment: But I just changed i to a Double just as well

Comment: Linking to a temporary code-drop site is a BAD idea.  That link will evaporate in a few days ... and your answer will then be broken.

Answer (score 2):

If `i` is an integer (which seems to be the case), then the `i/5` expression will perform integer math resulting in zero.

Answer (score 1):

`i` is not a double. Integer division floors. Anything times 0 is 0.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try

```
Double q = ((r * i/5.0) + y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Floating point values are notoriously imprecise. The difference you're showing can be expected for double arithmetic. If you really need the extra precision, [jquantity](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jquantity/) is an open source Java library for precise math.

Comment: The values used are well within the precision of `double`.